# android map overlay draw

Tags: android

I have made a map overlay class and have overridden the onTouchEvent method that looks like this :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
    {   
        //TO-DO here we will capture when the users
        //has pointed a point to go..
        if(event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                    (int) event.getX(),
                    (int) event.getY());

                Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
                    getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                        p.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
                        p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

                    String add = "";
                    if (addresses.size() > 0) 
                    {
                        for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); 
                             i++)
                           add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                    }
                    Log.e("##################",
                            "screen touched: lat:"+(p.getLatitudeE6()/ 1E6)+"long:"+(p.getLongitudeE6()/ 1E6));
                    showMap((p.getLatitudeE6()/ 1E6),(p.getLongitudeE6()/ 1E6));
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {                
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
                return true;
        }else
            return false;
    }
```

The problem is that the map is drawn every time I do a gesture on the map, I would like to do this only when I click on a spot on the map and not when I drag the map, is this approach correct? How to implement this?

Comment: what do you mean with spot? do you mean a certain location?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that my English aren't so good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)

They both tell you starting and stopping locations, so you could do a check like:

```
float x, y;
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    x = event.getRawX();
    y = event.getRawY();
} else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    if (((x - event.getRawX()) < threshhold_for_x) &&
        (y - event.getRawY()) < threshhold_for_y)) {

        // touch was in same location

    }
}
```

That's the general idea anyway, of course you need to reset x and y, and if they do a gesture and wind up in the same location it would trigger it...

You might be able to use `getDownTime ()` to make it work better.